# To have and to hold

Tags: riddle, pattern, enigmatic-puzzle, language

I found this odd list in an abandoned shack, tucked into the first few pages of the *Divine Comedy*. Can you help me figure out what exactly this person was collecting?

- The compendium of organs and bones
- The bloodletting of the North American lamb
- The animal both alive and dead
- The animal hungry for the ghost of food
- Lessons from the ancient animals
- Keep it simple, keep it simple, keep it simple
- Where Rome drew the line
- Euphoric music
- What the businessman wrote to save whoever he could
- The wishing well in the cave
- Choking forever on forbidden fruit!
- The hidden maze beneath Spain
- The weak point that Paris finally found
- The place of chains and flame with many shadows
- Never an unnecessary weapon on the wall!
- Where the spider revealed it could think
- The power of the machines doubles every odd year
- Evil in a jar!
- Child of Satan! Child of the herb!
- The three women of Heaven who answer to the hidden man
- The slave in his house of wood
- Everything will fall to pieces if it can
- Six hundred sextillion plus some
- The precious blunt instrument owned by a murderous doctor in training
- He lurks even now in the waters of the Valley
- The wild carrot!

Comment: Is the *Divine Comedy* reference relevant, or just for flavour?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Complete collaborated answer

These are all

> common phrases including a possessive:

- The compendium of organs and bones

  > [Gray's Anatomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray%27s_Anatomy)
- The bloodletting of the North American lamb

  > [Custer's Last Stand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Little_Bighorn) (from 'bloodletting'=Battle and 'North American lamb'=Little Bighorn
- The animal both alive and dead

  > [Schrödinger's cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_Cat)
- The animal hungry for the ghost of food

  > [Pavlov's dog](http://www.simplypsychology.org/pavlov.html)
- Lessons from the ancient animals

  > [Aesop's Fables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aesop%27s_Fables)
- Keep it simple, keep it simple, keep it simple

  > [Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor)
- Where Rome drew the line

  > [Hadrian's wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadrian%27s_Wall)
- Euphoric music

  > [Beethoven's 9th (Ode to Joy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphony_No._9_%28Beethoven%29)
- What the businessman wrote to save whoever he could

  > [Schindler's list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schindlerjuden#List_of_Schindlerjuden)
- The wishing well in the cave

  > [Aladdin's lamp](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aladdin)
- Choking forever on forbidden fruit!

  > [Adam's apple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam%27s_apple)
- The hidden maze beneath Spain

  > [*Pan's Labyrinth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan%27s_Labyrinth)
- The weak point that Paris finally found

  > [Achilles's heel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achilles%27_heel)
- The place of chains and flame with many shadows

  > [Plato's cave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory_of_the_Cave)
- Never an unnecessary weapon on the wall!

  > [Chekhov's gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chekhov%27s_gun)
- Where the spider revealed it could think

  > [*Charlotte's Web*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlotte%27s_Web)
- The power of the machines doubles every odd year

  > [Moore's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law)
- Evil in a jar!

  > [Pandora's Box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandora%27s_box)
- Child of Satan! Child of the herb!

  > [*Rosemary's Baby*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosemary%27s_Baby)
- The three women of Heaven who answer to the hidden man

  > [*Charlie's Angels*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlie%27s_Angels)
- The slave in his house of wood

  > [*Uncle Tom's Cabin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncle_Tom%27s_Cabin)
- Everything will fall to pieces if it can

  > [Murphy's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law)
- Six hundred sextillion plus some

  > [Avogadro's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro%27s_number)
- The precious blunt instrument owned by a murderous doctor in training

  > [*Maxwell's Silver Hammer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_Silver_Hammer)
- He lurks even now in the waters of the Valley

  > [Montezuma's Revenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traveler%27s_diarrhea#Montezuma.27s_revenge)
- The wild carrot!

  > [Queen Anne's Lace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daucus_carota)

Answer (score 2):

He lurks even now...

> Montezuma's Revenge

Comment: Beautiful - that must be it!  Nice job!

Comment: Excellent work!

Comment: Good job!  Bounty awarded.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution to:

> *"He lurks even now in the waters of the Valley"*

---

<strike>**Kings' Valley (Valley of Kings)**</strike> 
 **Evidence:** During periodic thunder storms, the central area of the valley floods. Historical floods have caused some tombs to shift five meters into the ground. In fact, one of the tombs so shifted is KV62, the burial chamber that King Tut's remains were found in. Perhaps the "He" refers to Tut or another of the many Pharaohs whose ghosts could still "lurk...in the waters of the Valley" and who would be important enough for the specific "He" to make sense.
 **Sources:**
 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valley_of_the_Kings
 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutankhamun.
 **Additional:** Valley of Kings == Kings' Valley. The quote "waters of the Valley" could also simply refer to the Nile, which lies directly adjacent to the Valley of Kings and is the source for the flooding during storms.  

 **Other Suggestion(s):**

> - Helm's Deep

Comment: Not what I was thinking of. The real answer always has an apostrophe as opposed to "of the."

Comment: FYI- Stack doesn't alert the poster when you've updated a post, so You might want to include a comment notifying him if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However, since the level of uncertainty in this answer is so much higher, I'd rather refrain from spamming OP with a deluge of miscellaneous guesses lacking in evidence. Thus it's just a suggestion to be viewed and contemplated.